# How to disable a Button with a style for Button.Content tag in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a Button like this:

```
<Button x:Name="CloseBtn" Click="CloseBtn_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsCloseEnabled}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource TopButton}">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Height="30" Width="30" Source="{StaticResource CloseIcon}" />
                            <Label Foreground="Black">Close</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
```

Its style is this:

```
<Style x:Key="TopButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#FFADADAD"/>
                </Trigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

However when the binding "IsCloseEnabled" returns false, the button doesn't look like being disabled -- the color "#FFADADAD" isn't applied to the foreground.  Not sure where it goes wrong.

Comment: `Label Foreground="Black"` - why would this change if Button Foreground changes? try to create a Binding between Label Foreground and Button Foreground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Label has a hardset value of Foreground="Black", which will override any other color you try to apply via triggers.  Remove the "Foreground=Black" and see if that fixes your problem.

Update #2: If you also want to control the image to look disabled, you're better off making the image source controlled by a style which replaces the source with a "disabled" png.  Something like this:

```
        <Button x:Name="CloseBtn" Click="CloseBtn_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsCloseEnabled}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource TopButton}">
            <Button.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="myImage" Height="30" Width="30">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Image">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource CloseIcon}"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCloseEnabled}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource CloseIconDisabled}"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <Label>Close</Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

Comment: By removing the ""Foreground=Black" the Close caption looks disabled.  Thanks!  However I also want to the image (CloseIcon) looks disabled.  Is there a way doing it?

Comment: Your CloseIcon is just an image, and there is no way to magically make it look greyed out.  You'd have to create a disabled-looking CloseIcon image (maybe call it CloseDisabledIcon), then you'd swap to using that one in your trigger, just like you're currently swapping to a different TextBlock.Foreground in your trigger.

Comment: I tried this but not working:  <Style x:Key="TopButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BigDefaultButton}">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#FFADADAD"/>
                        <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{StaticResource CloseIconDisabled}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    
                </Style.Triggers>

            </Style>

Comment: CloseIconDisabled is defined like this:  <BitmapImage x:Key="CloseIconDisabled" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/Buttons/close-grey.png" />

Comment: You can't do that because a Button doesn't contain any Image object in its default ControlTemplate (but it does have TextBlocks which is why the TextBlock.Foreground works).  See my updated answer on how to control the image source.  And if that works, please mark as answered.